# Why would recvfrom() used on a stream socket return a zero address and port?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, recvfrom

I am using a Linux system, not a Windows system. I've posted some code, below. Please bear in mind that this code was never intended to be "production quality."

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 9909

void die ( const char *fmt, ... )
{
    va_list vargs;
    va_start( vargs, fmt );
    vfprintf( stderr, fmt, vargs );
    va_end( vargs );
    exit( 1 );
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    /* *** */
    int listener = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    if( listener < 0 ) die( "socket(listener)" );

    int flag = 1;
    if( setsockopt( listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&flag, sizeof(int) ) < 0 )
        die( "setsockopt()" );

    struct sockaddr_in svr_addr;
    memset( &svr_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr) );
        svr_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
        svr_addr.sin_port = htons( PORT );
        svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if( bind( listener, (struct sockaddr*)&svr_addr, (socklen_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr) ) < 0 )
        die( "bind()" );

    if( listen( listener, 10 ) < 0 )
        die( "listen()" );

    /* *** */

    fd_set fd_master;
    fd_set fd_select;
    int fd_max = listener; 

    FD_ZERO( &fd_master );
    FD_ZERO( &fd_select );

    FD_SET( listener, &fd_master );

    while( 1 )
    {
        fd_select = fd_master;
        if( select( fd_max + 1, &fd_select, NULL, NULL, NULL ) < 0 )
            die( "select()" );

        for( int ifd = 0; ifd <= fd_max; ++ifd )
        {
            if( ! FD_ISSET( ifd, &fd_select ) ) continue;

            struct sockaddr_in cli_addr; memset( &cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr) );
            socklen_t cli_alen = sizeof(cli_addr);

            if( ifd == listener )
            {
                int cli = accept( listener, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &cli_alen );
                if( cli < 0 ) die( "accept()" );

                FD_SET( cli, &fd_master );
                if( cli > fd_max ) fd_max = cli;
                printf( "new connection> %s:%u\n", inet_ntoa( cli_addr.sin_addr ), ntohs( cli_addr.sin_port ) );
                fflush( stdout );
            }
            else
            {
                char buf[256];
                cli_alen = sizeof(cli_addr);
                ssize_t nbytes = recvfrom( ifd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &cli_alen );
                if( nbytes <= 0 )
                {
                    close( ifd );
                    FD_CLR( ifd, &fd_master );
                    if( nbytes == 0 )
                        printf( "connection hung up> %u\n", ifd );
                    else
                        printf( "recvfrom() : %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
                    fflush( stdout );
                }
                else
                {
                    // build a "from identifier" for each of the recipients
                    char msg[sizeof(buf) * 2];
                    sprintf( msg, "%s:%u> ", inet_ntoa( cli_addr.sin_addr ), ntohs( cli_addr.sin_port ) );
                    memcpy( msg + strlen( msg ), buf, nbytes );
                    nbytes += strlen( msg );

                    // send incoming data to all clients (excluding the originator)
                    for( int ofd = 0; ofd <= fd_max; ++ofd )
                    {
                        if( FD_ISSET( ofd, &fd_master ) )
                            if( ofd != listener && ofd != ifd )
                                if( send( ofd, msg, nbytes, 0 ) < 0 )
                                    { printf( "send() %s\n", strerror( errno ) ); fflush( stdout ); }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the code is run and you connect from two or more clients (via telnet), each message shows the sender as "0.0.0.0" with a port of 0.

The Windows documentation for recvfrom() states "[t]he *from* and *fromlen* parameters are ignored for connection-oriented sockets." The Linux and POSIX documentation make no such claim and goes as far as to say that recvfrom() "...may be used to receive data on a socket whether or not it is connection-oriented." No where does it say that *src_addr* and *addrlen* will be ignored ... so I would expect these to be filled in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On connected sockets you have to call `getpeername` and then carry on with your `inet_ntoa` (consider using `inet_ntop` instead as it supports multiple address families). As per the man pages:

```
int getpeername(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address, socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Nowhere does it say that *src_addr* and *addrlen* will be ignored.

That is simply untrue. It says

> If src_addr is not NULL, *and the underlying protocol provides the source address*, this source address is filled in. [emphasis added]

You can argue about whether TCP can be said to provide the source address, but you can't claim 'nowhere does it say ...'.