# Port of client is not displayed correctly

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm running a server program which can service multi clients on Ubuntu16 (Virtual machine).

This is how I test the program:

- Open 4 shells
- Run server program on the first shell
- Run client program on the other 3 shells

This is the log of the server program:

```bash
Blocked on select system call...
New connection request detected
Add [4] to the set
Accept connection from client 127.0.0.1:45628
Blocked on select system call...
New connection request detected
Add [5] to the set
Accept connection from client 127.0.0.1:45630
Blocked on select system call...
New connection request detected
Add [6] to the set
Accept connection from client 127.0.0.1:45632
Blocked on select system call...
```

After that, I send data from client, and this is the log of server:

```bash
Blocked on select system call...
New data on [5]
addrlen=16, before recvfrom
addrlen=0, after recvfrom
Server received 8 bytes from 127.0.0.1:45646
Server sent 4 bytes in reply to 127.0.0.1:45646
Blocked on select system call...
New data on [4]
addrlen=0, before recvfrom
addrlen=0, after recvfrom
Server received 8 bytes from 127.0.0.1:45646
Server sent 4 bytes in reply to 127.0.0.1:45646
Blocked on select system call...
New data on [5]
addrlen=0, before recvfrom
addrlen=0, after recvfrom
Server received 8 bytes from 127.0.0.1:45646
Server sent 4 bytes in reply to 127.0.0.1:45646
Blocked on select system call...
```

As you can see, when I send data from client whose socket is `[4]`, port number is `45628`; the log of server displays socket number correctly execpt port number, which is `45632`.

How should I fix this?

---

Server's src code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "common.h"

#define SERVER_PORT     2000
#define MAX_PENDING_LEN 5
#define MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED 32

test_struct_t test_struct;
result_struct_t res_struct;
char data_buffer[1024];
fd_set s_readfds; // s stands for Server
int monitored_fd_set[MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED];

static void init_monitored_fd_set(int *set)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED; i++) {
        set[i] = -1;
    }
}

static void add_to_monitored_fd_set(int fd, int *set)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED; i++) {
        if (set[i] == -1) {
            set[i] = fd;
            break;
        }
    }
}

static void rm_from_monitored_fd_set(int fd, int *set) 
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED; i++) {
        if (set[i] == fd) {
            set[i] = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

static void re_init_readfds(fd_set *p_readfds, int *set)
{
    int i;
    
    FD_ZERO(p_readfds);
    
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED; i++) {
        if (set[i] != -1) {
            FD_SET(set[i], p_readfds);
        }
    }
}

static int get_max_fd(int *set)
{
    int max_fd = -1;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED; i++) {
        if (set[i] > max_fd) {
            max_fd = set[i];
        }
    }

    return max_fd;
}

void start_server_proc(in_port_t port, uint32_t address)
{
    int master_socket = 0;
    int con_socket_fd = 0;
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    int i;
    int sent_recv_bytes;

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    
    master_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (master_socket == -1) {
        printf("Failed to create master socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = port;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = address;

    if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to bind socket\n");
        return;
    }

    if (listen(master_socket, MAX_PENDING_LEN) < 0) {
        printf("Server failed to listen\n");
        return;
    }

    init_monitored_fd_set(monitored_fd_set);
    add_to_monitored_fd_set(master_socket, monitored_fd_set);

    while(1) {
        re_init_readfds(&s_readfds, monitored_fd_set);
        
        printf("Blocked on select system call...\n");
        select(get_max_fd(monitored_fd_set) + 1, &s_readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &s_readfds)) { // New connection request
            printf("New connection request detected\n");
            con_socket_fd = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);

            if (con_socket_fd < 0) {
                printf("Failed to accept connection\n");
                exit (0);
            } else {
                printf("Add [%d] to the set\n", con_socket_fd);
        add_to_monitored_fd_set(con_socket_fd, monitored_fd_set);
                printf("Accept connection from client %s:%u\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
            }
        } else { // New incoming data from clients
             for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT_SUPPORTED; i++) {
                if (FD_ISSET(monitored_fd_set[i], &s_readfds)) {
                    printf("New data on [%d]\n", monitored_fd_set[i]);
            memset(data_buffer, 0, sizeof(data_buffer));
                    // sent_recv_bytes = recv(monitored_fd_set[i], data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), 0);
                    sent_recv_bytes = recvfrom(monitored_fd_set[i], data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);

                    printf("Server received %u bytes from %s:%u\n", sent_recv_bytes, inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

                    if (sent_recv_bytes == 0) {
                        close(monitored_fd_set[i]);
                        rm_from_monitored_fd_set(monitored_fd_set[i], monitored_fd_set);
                        printf("Received 0 byte => Close connection\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    test_struct_t *client_data = (test_struct_t *)data_buffer;
                   
                    if ((client_data->a == 0) && (client_data->b == 0)) {
                        close(monitored_fd_set[i]);
                        rm_from_monitored_fd_set(monitored_fd_set[i], monitored_fd_set);
                        printf("Invalid data => Close connection\n");
                        break;
                    }

                    result_struct_t result;
                    result.c = client_data->a + client_data->b;
                    // sent_recv_bytes = send(monitored_fd_set[i], (char *)&result, sizeof(result_struct_t), 0);
                    sent_recv_bytes = sendto(monitored_fd_set[i], (char *)&result, sizeof(result_struct_t), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, addr_len);
                    printf("Server sent %d bytes in reply to %s:%u\n", sent_recv_bytes, inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
                }
             }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    start_server_proc(SERVER_PORT, INADDR_ANY);
}
```

---

Client's src code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include "common.h"

#define DEST_PORT            2000
#define SERVER_IP_ADDRESS   "127.0.0.1"

test_struct_t client_data;
result_struct_t result;

void
setup_tcp_communication(){

    /*Step 1 : Initialization*/
    /*Socket handle*/
    int sockfd = 0, 
        sent_recv_bytes = 0;

    int addr_len = 0;

    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    /*to store socket addesses : ip address and port*/
    struct sockaddr_in dest;

    /*Step 2: specify server information*/
    /*Ipv4 sockets, Other values are IPv6*/
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;

    /*Client wants to send data to server process which is running on server machine, and listening on 
     * port on DEST_PORT, server IP address SERVER_IP_ADDRESS.
     * Inform client about which server to send data to : All we need is port number, and server ip address. Pls note that
     * there can be many processes running on the server listening on different no of ports, 
     * our client is interested in sending data to server process which is lisetning on PORT = DEST_PORT*/ 
    dest.sin_port = DEST_PORT;
    struct hostent *host = (struct hostent *)gethostbyname(SERVER_IP_ADDRESS);
    dest.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);

    /*Step 3 : Create a TCP socket*/
    /*Create a socket finally. socket() is a system call, which asks for three paramemeters*/
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);


    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest,sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    /*Step 4 : get the data to be sent to server*/
    /*Our client is now ready to send data to server. sendto() sends data to Server*/

PROMPT_USER:

    /*prompt the user to enter data*/
    printf("Enter a : ?\n");
    scanf("%u", &client_data.a);
    printf("Enter b : ?\n");
    scanf("%u", &client_data.b);

    
    /*step 5 : send the data to server*/
    sent_recv_bytes = sendto(sockfd, 
           &client_data,
           sizeof(test_struct_t), 
           0, 
           (struct sockaddr *)&dest, 
           sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    
    printf("No of bytes sent = %d\n", sent_recv_bytes);
   
    /*Step 6 : Client also want to reply from server after sending data*/
    
    /*recvfrom is a blocking system call, meaning the client program will not run past this point
     * untill the data arrives on the socket from server*/
    sent_recv_bytes =  recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)&result, sizeof(result_struct_t), 0,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &addr_len);

    printf("No of bytes recvd = %d\n", sent_recv_bytes);
    
    printf("Result recvd = %u\n", result.c);
    /*Step 7: Client would want to send the data again to the server, go into infinite loop*/
    goto PROMPT_USER;
}
    

int
main(int argc, char **argv){

    setup_tcp_communication();
    printf("application quits\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your tutorials and books say about the port number, and their ***byte order***?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it does not mention anything about the port number, the tutorial is about `select()` and TCP server with multiplexing.

Comment: What is the value of `addr_len` in `start_server_proc()` before and after the call to `recvfrom()`?

Comment: That's an "advanced" topic when it comes to network programming. What does the *beginners* tutorials or books say? They never told you about e.g. `htons`? You *do* know that TCP/IP have "network byte order" and "host byte order"?

Comment: @IanAbbott I updated the log of server.

Comment: On a tcp / stream socket, [`recvfrom()` ignores the client address and address_len arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771919/why-would-recvfrom-used-on-a-stream-socket-return-a-zero-address-and-port).  Use `getpeername()` instead.

Comment: `recvfrom()` set your `addr_len` to 0 to indicate that it is not returning any address information. The `client_addr` variable still contains the previous address information from `accept()` because it has not been set by `recvfrom()`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, `addr_len` may in fact be set to zero; however, as I read them, neither the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvfrom.html) nor [Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) descriptions mandate this.  They imply that `addr_len` is left alone if the underlying socket protocol does not convey sender addresses.

Comment: @pilcrow it seems like I can conlude that, "the TCP does not provide the source address for the message, so `client_addr` and `addr_len` is not updated by `recvfrom()` in the program", right?

Comment: @dustin2022 yes that’s right.

Comment: `server_addr.sin_port = port;` should be `server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);`. Same in the client program. Please don't tell me you've never seen this before. You correctly use `ntohs` when printing the port, what made you forget the corresponding `htons` when setting up the port?

Answer (score -2):

I think you should print the correspondence between `con_socket_fd` and subscript on the server side, so that the problem can be located more clearly.

Comment: This is not an answer for the question, it is rather a comment, because it does not explain the issue. You need to wait until you have enough reputation to comment.